# Snort monitoring of spanning interface

Tags: linux, snort, ids

I have configured a Cisco 3500 switch with a port SPAN and have my snort node (fedora 13) plugged into it. I am running snort as a daemon and have configured a rule to log all tcp traffic but I am only seeing traffic with a destination of the snort node. I know that the SPAN port is working and wanted to know if there is a specific option that I needed to start snort with in order for it to pickup all the traffic? Or is there something that I have missed here?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you perhaps mix up your source and destinations for the SPAN?

Comment: Do the snort interfaces need to have a default gateway?

Comment: Also the span should be as follows: 

set span source_port destination_port [rx | tx | both]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the configurations that shipped with your package, you may have some settings wrong. The base snort.conf file should work, however you should inspect the system config file `/etc/sysconfig/snort` and make sure these two options are set sanely.

- INTERFACE
- BPF

Also you should look at the system log, `/var/log/messages` by default, to see if the interface is actually entering promiscuous mode. If so, you should see something along these lines

> kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode

You can also get good debugging information from the perfmonitor preprocessor. You can enable it in your snort.conf with something like

```
preprocessor perfmonitor: time 300 file /var/log/snort/snort.stats pktcnt 10000
```

This will dump a *VERY* large comma delineated list of performance values from the snort application. The full list of all the values dumped can be found in the manual, either shipped or at [snort_manual.pdf](http://www.snort.org/assets/156/snort_manual.pdf)  You might be interested to look at:

- Total Packets Received
- Mbits/Sec (applayer)
- TCP Sessions Initializing

The values from those, and possibly others, should help determine whether the application itself is even seeing the packets, let alone processing them.